# run Firebase locally

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am new with Firebase and I am struggling with its docs for an 2 hours now, and I can´t figure out how to run my local project with Firebase (Firebase for web).

My app is like:

```
-- node_modules
-- app
  -- index.html
  -- src
    -- css, js, etc.
```

Basically I want to run my app from app/index.html. I have installed `firebase tools`, run `firebase init` (i am not familiar with all init options) and then run `firebase serve`.

It throws error "an unexpected error has occurred", probably due to missing public directory (but I don't want any "public" dir in my app).

I have also put firebase app code from my Firebase project to my index.html, but it logs error: `Error: Illegal url for new iframe` and `This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.`

Comment: "but I dont want any "public" dir in my app" Why not? Seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Just want to keep my file structue as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you init, it creates a file:

> firebase.json

that looks like this:

```
{
  "firebase": "yourProjectName",
  "public": "./someFolder",
  "ignore": []
}
```

The folder that is being served is the one specified by the public property.
So if you want to serve the app folder of your project you just have to replace the string:

```
  "public": "./app",
```

This error happens because you didn't authorize operations.

> This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase
>   project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console

You have to login via the console using the command:

```
firebase login
```

Then, it will open the browser and ask for authorization if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day! Except the .json file. It looks more like: {
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./app"
  }
}

Comment: I guess the v3.0 syntax changed for this file

Answer (score 4):

Double check your authDomain value being passed to the payload for initializeApp(). I had accidentally had a trailing comma at the end by way of the .env file.

Comment: I had a trailing comma too.

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate the firebase configuration if you add https:// with the firebase authDomain, you won't be able to use firebase authentication in localhost because it doesn't contain https. Remove the https:// from the authDomain URL. It'll work.